# How do I disable or change the caps lock key on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

We have ergonomic keyboards at work which I'm not entirely used to. I seem to keep hitting the capslock key while I'm in `vim` and it's starting to annoy. How can I disable this key, and or change to to be another key?

Comment: Related: [Remapping caps-lock to escape, and menu to compose, on the linux console](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7670/remapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-menu-to-compose-on-the-linux-console). Do you want this only in X, or in your OS (which?)'s console?

Answer (score 7):

The quick and dirty way to disable it is with `xmodmap`:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
```

The next question is what would you like to do with it? I usually make it either a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Control_L'
```

Depending on your DE/WM, there is likely a way to do this in the GUI configuration. For example Gnome has a "keyboard layout" option on the control pannels with an options tab that includes several similar layout modifications.

Comment: Arrr, too fast 4 me ;)
Anyway, so just added a `setxkbmap` solution to my answer then...

Answer (score 6):

Use `xmodmap`.

The setting to disable your capslock is

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
```

This would be placed in your `.xmodmap` file.

Another option - to disable it temporarily, you can use a `setxkbmap` option:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

and then, to restore normal behavior:  `setxkbmap -option`

Answer (score 3):

Using xmodmap will only change the key binding while in X. If you need it on the console it's a little different. The changes below will modify X as well as the console, so I always do it this way.

For **Linux** add this to /etc/rc.local (or make an init script):

```
(echo $(dumpkeys |grep -i keymaps); echo keycode 58 = Control) | loadkeys -
```

For **Solaris** on a PC with a USB keyboard edit `/usr/share/lib/keytables/type_6/reset` (for other types of keyboards you would replace `type_6` with the appropriate type):

Locate this line:

```
key 57   all shiftkeys+capslock
```

Replace with this:

```
key 57   all shiftkeys+leftctrl up shiftkeys+leftctrl
```

Naturally you can replace <kbd>Control</kbd> with any key you would like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a portion of my `.xmodmaprc`, that turns <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> into <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and vice versa:

```
clear lock

keycode 9 = Caps_Lock ISO_Next_Group Caps_Lock ISO_Next_Group
keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape

add lock = Caps_Lock
```

You can check the keycodes by running `xev` and just pressing the buttons you want to check.

Comment: This is quite handy for use in Vi/Vim