# Remap Caps_Lock to Control in Solaris

Tags: x11, solaris, xmodmap

I'm having the hardest time trying to understand how `xmodmap` works. I want to remap the Caps Lock key to Control.

In an attempt to emaulate [the answers shown here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17894/how-do-i-disable-or-change-the-caps-lock-key-on-my-keyboard), I created the file `.xmodmaprc`:

```
clear Lock
keycode 65 = Control_L 
# I got the value 65 from running xev and pressing the key.
```

Then I added the following to .kshrc:

```
export XMODMAPRC="/Home/username/.xmodmaprc"
[ -f $XMODMAPRC ] && echo "OK" && xmodmap $XMODMAPRC
```

When I launch a new xterm, I can see the "OK" printed at login, but the key is still behaving as a Caps Lock!

How can I make this work?

I work on **Solaris 10** and I **don't have root access**.

Comment: [Not .kshrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085), but your X session startup script. I don't know what that is for Solaris 10.

Comment: I finally got it. I'm accessing a Solaris server from a Windows host and I run X locally. It was [Exceed](http://connectivity.opentext.com/products/exceed-products.aspx) that needed remapping. X's notion of server/client is confusing. [Here's how to do it on Exceed](http://nstx.pppl.gov/nstx/Software/FAQ/exceedtips.html). @Gilles thanks for your comment, it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me; it swaps the Caps Lock and left Control keys.

```
#!/bin/sh

xmodmap - <<EOF
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
EOF
```

If you want both keys to act as Control keys, you'll have to modify this; I frankly don't understand xmodmap well enough myself to do so, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: It doesn't work. Did you try it on Solaris? Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it on Solaris, and I don't have access to a Solaris X server.  Ubuntu (Linux) lets you remap the control key through the preferences GUI; does Solaris have something similar?