# How do I remap Caps_lock to Ctrl from inside emacs?

Tags: emacs

I use emacs on several machines between work and home, and I'm naturally interested in remapping that Caps_Lock key to save my finger from agony. On [some platforms](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29784/4098) it's a bit more difficult to do than one would like, the interface to the X server is far from being user-friendly.

On the other hand, I managed to set up a simple system to share my emacs configuration across machines. Since the remapping of the key is mainly useful inside emacs, is there a way to remap CapsLock to Control (and vice-versa) **inside emacs only**?

If it makes any difference, I use emacs 24.1.

Comment: It may not be possible, or if possible, trivial, at least according to [Moving The Ctrl Key](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc22) page of the Emacs wiki.

Comment: The OS (more precisely X) treats CapsLock and Ctrl specially, so you can't. You need to do it at the level of the X server. (Ok, strictly speaking you can, but it'll play hell with the CapsLock functionality unless you deactivate that on the X server, and I don't think Emacs has any code to do it.)