# How to use CapsLock instead of Escape in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to map my <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Escape</kbd>. How do I represent <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in `.vimrc`?

I know to map space to a command I would do something like this:

```
:map <space> viw
```

How would I map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Escape</kbd> without doing a registry hack - I'm looking for a Vim command?

If that is not possible without a hack or additional software I would like to assign the shortcut <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd> in `.vimrc` . I'm currently doing this:

```
inoremap jj <esc>
```

However if I'm in visual mode this does not work. How could I make <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> emulate the escape key?

Comment: Are you wanting this in X, the console or both? Also, please look at my edits and format your last edit as per the site styles.

Comment: Related question on SuperUser: [keyboard layout - Map capslock to control in Windows 10 - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/949385/map-capslock-to-control-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think you can map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> from within Vim. You remap it within X using [`setxkbmap`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml):

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

For remapping in the console, if your distro uses `systemd`, you can use a custom keyboard layout in `/etc/vconsole.conf` as described on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console#Persistent_configuration), and for other init systems see [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7670/remapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-menu-to-compose-on-the-linux-console).

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: How do you set it so both are escape?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to map both <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> to <kbd>Escape</kbd>, instead of swapping them, use

```
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

instead of `...:swapescape`.

Use

```
setxkbmap -option
```

to clear any existing options, then the above should work.

Comment: what if I want to undo that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a call to `xmodmap` on Vim startup to map Capslock to Escape. The modification can be reverted once you leave Vim. Add the following lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
au VimEnter * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
au VimLeave * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock'
```

However, this will lead to problems if you have multiple Vim sessions. Once you close one of them, the modification is reverted for all of them, since `xmodmap` operates globally.

Comment: nice answer ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/21127352/2065674

Answer (score 1):

inoremap means insert mode non-recursive map. 
vnoremap is visual mode non-recursive map.
So 
`vnoremap jj <esc>`
is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc` file :

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * !setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
:autocmd BufWinLeave * !setxkbmap -option
```

Instead of the first line, you can use an alias in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` :

```
alias vim="setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape && vim"
```

The drawback in these approaches being that as long as you haven't closed the vim, your CapsLock will be your Escape and vice-versa, machine-wide.

#### Solution to that:

For this, I am using timeout with the key-binding swap only during the required mode (that is, InsertMode):

```
au CursorHoldI * stopinsert
au InsertEnter * silent! let updaterestore=&updatetime | set updatetime=15000 | execute "!setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape" | redraw!
au InsertLeave * silent! let &updatetime=updaterestore | execute "!setxkbmap -option" | redraw!
```

Now, during the InsertMode, the CapsLock and Escape will interchange machine-wide, but since I have set a time-out for the InsertMode to be 15000, I need not worry about it as it will automatically be reversed in 15 seconds of inactivity. ;-)

-*Himanshu*

Comment: Doesn't this method also mean that if you close one of two windows, then you loose the remap?

Comment: Well I (personally) only want the remap during insert mode (during typing). Otherwise I'm happy to use the Esc key as escape key. Hence the solution..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming from Ubuntu 22.04 and having issues with

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

An [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415659/1621463) provides an alternative method:

```
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options" "[ 'caps:swapescape']"
```

Answer (score 0):

> However if I'm in visual mode this does not work. How could I make jj emulate the escape key?

That's because you are only mapping `jj` in insert mode (defined by the i in `inoremap`)

For visual and normal mode, respectively, add this to your `.vimrc` file (or `init.vim` for Neovim):

```
vnoremap jj <ESC>
nnoremap jj <ESC>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone requiring both esc ***and*** control as caps this guide is useful https://www.dannyguo.com/blog/remap-caps-lock-to-escape-and-control/ (not possible via vim config alone AFAIK)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/433290)